# Searching and replacing in binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, replace, binary

First of all, I tried these questions and didn't work for me:

- [Python search and replace in binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162614/python-search-and-replace-in-binary-file)
- [python re module to replace the binary data inside a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621280/python-re-module-to-replace-the-binary-data-inside-a-text-file)

I'm working in manipulating a pdf file in binary.  I need to replace a string by other.

This is my approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

with open("proof.pdf", "rb") as input_file:
    content = input_file.read()
    if b"21.8182 686.182 261.818 770.182" in content:
        print("FOUND!!")
    content.replace(b"21.8182 686.182 261.818 770.182", b"1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1")
    if b"1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1" in content:
        print("REPLACED!!")

with open("proof_output.pdf", "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(content)
```

When I run the script it shows "FOUND!!", but not "REPLACED!!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `string replace` and `sub` in python `re` do not carry out inplace replacements. In both the cases you get another string with your replacement.

Replace:-

```
content.replace(b"21.8182 686.182 261.818 770.182", b"1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1")
```

with

```
content = content.replace(b"21.8182 686.182 261.818 770.182", b"1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1")
```

This should work.